# Some SDL functions are not recognized by gcc

Tags: c, linux, sdl, sdl-2

I'm learning to use SDL and unfortunately I don't understand why gcc on linux misunderstands my code and interprets it with other functions and gives me these compilation errors. I don't see where that could come from.

disco.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

void SDLdebugError();

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

  SDL_Window SDL_CreateWindow("Chicken Disco", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SET_WINDOW_OPENGL);
  if(window == NULL) { SDLdebugError("Window Error"); };

  SDL_Quit();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void SDLdebugError(char *message) {
  printf("%s, %s\n", message, SDL_GetError());
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

compilation :

```
disco.c: In function ‘main’:
disco.c:12:3: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_Window’; did you mean ‘SDL_cond’?
   SDL_Window SDL_CreateWindow("Chicken Disco", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SET_WINDOW_OPENGL);
   ^~~~~~~~~~
   SDL_cond
disco.c:12:31: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
   SDL_Window SDL_CreateWindow("Chicken Disco", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SET_WINDOW_OPENGL);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
disco.c:12:48: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED’; did you mean ‘SDL_HAT_CENTERED’?
   SDL_Window SDL_CreateWindow("Chicken Disco", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SET_WINDOW_OPENGL);
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                SDL_HAT_CENTERED
disco.c:12:72: error: unknown type name ‘SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED’; did you mean ‘SDL_HAT_CENTERED’?
 DL_Window SDL_CreateWindow("Chicken Disco", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SET_WINDOW_OPENGL);
                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                     SDL_HAT_CENTERED
disco.c:12:96: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 ow("Chicken Disco", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SET_WINDOW_OPENGL);
                                                                     ^~~

disco.c:12:101: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 hicken Disco", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SET_WINDOW_OPENGL);
                                                                     ^~~

disco.c:12:106: error: unknown type name ‘SET_WINDOW_OPENGL’; did you mean ‘SDL_VIDEO_OPENGL’?
 n Disco", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SET_WINDOW_OPENGL);
                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                     SDL_VIDEO_OPENGL
disco.c:13:6: error: ‘window’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘rindex’?
   if(window == NULL) { SDLdebugError("Window Error"); };
      ^~~~~~
      rindex
```

Comment: `SDL_Window SDL_CreateWindow("` is kind-of invalid syntax. YYou mean `SDL_Window window = SDL_CreateWindow("` ?

Comment: For Unix-y systems SDL2 usually installs `SDL.h` to `<prefix>/SDL2/SDL.h`; SDL 1.2's `SDL.h` lives in `<prefix>/SDL/SDL.h`.  You can usually rely on [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) to tell you where/what the SDL2 includes/libs live/are: `gcc \`pkg-config --cflags sdl2\` main.c \`pkg-config --libs sdl2\``

Comment: Yup, you seem to be using old SDL1 instead of SDL2.

Comment: `SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(...`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the `window` variable. That should fix all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your answers. Finally genpfault was right, I reinstalled libsdl2-dev via apt and replaced

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

by

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

and compiled with: ``` gcc disco.c ``sdl2-config --cflags --libs`` -o disco ```

And I also declared the window variable: D (Jordan Motta)